# Slowing down scroll top jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I don't know much about jquery and picked up this snippet, but it is not scrolling, just going to that page section instantly even if I set time to 5000 or more. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the error message on console. demo.js is my file and min.js is external script.

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])
at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at n (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (demo.js:27)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: The click event on the link is not being cancelled.  Unless it falls into the secondary `if` and `return false;`.  So you need to add some console.log statements or debug and find out why it's not going in there.

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] snippet in the question?  Your code as presented works perfectly, so there must be some other issue.  Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg276tpw/

Comment: Have you used `$.fx.off = true` anywhere to disable animation?  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/